# Webapi exception when Entity Framework has bidirectional associations

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I've created entity framework 6 boilerplate code from a database using code first and I can retrieve my data fine and see all my tables in list objects just fine, so I know retrieval is fine and any lazy loading is working.

However when returning the list from a webapi rest service it only works for my simple class (BikeStation below) which has no associated lists, when I try my classes which have references to other objects, it generates an exception to do with data contracts and seems to be linked to circular references

Here are my classes:

```
public partial class BikeStation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CentreName { get; set; }
    public string StationName { get; set; }
}

public partial class Bike
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Bike()
    {
        BikeStats = new HashSet<BikeStat>();
    }

    public string ShortBikeName { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<BikeStat> BikeStats { get; set; }
}

public partial class BikeStat
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StatDate { get; set; }
    public virtual Bike Bike { get; set; }
}
```

This works:

```
    public IEnumerable<BikeStation> Get()
    {
        using (var db = new BikesContext())
        {
            var a = db.BikeStations.ToList();
            return a;
        }
    }
```

However, changing to either of the other two gets the list fine but then fails to serialise the data:

```
    public IEnumerable<Bike> Get()
    {
        using (var db = new BikesContext())
        {
            var a = db.Bikes.ToList();
            return a;
        }
    }
```

If I remove the reference to the bike or bikestats in either of my other classes, it works just fine.

The error is this, and I don't really understand why it's trying to serialise as XML either. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<Error><Message>An error has occurred.</Message><ExceptionMessage>The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.</ExceptionMessage><ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType><StackTrace /><InnerException><Message>An error has occurred.</Message><ExceptionMessage>Type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Bike_16DB1847327CF3674DCB6407C4CCB0E41EA43002E17C91F35F5B4716F57DAD1D' with data contract name 'Bike_16DB1847327CF3674DCB6407C4CCB0E41EA43002E17C91F35F5B4716F57DAD1D:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer.</ExceptionMessage><ExceptionType>System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException</ExceptionType><StackTrace>   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at WriteArrayOfBikeToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiTypeAtTopLevel(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle originalDeclaredTypeHandle, Type graphType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.WriteObject(XmlWriter writer, Object graph)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.&lt;WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync&gt;d__1b.MoveNext()</StackTrace></InnerException></Error>
```

I then changed my code to explicitly convert the code using a custom class, which works but isn't ideal:

```
var newData = d.Select(x => new Bike()
            {
                Active = x.Active,
                ShortBikeName = x.ShortBikeName,
                BikeStats = (x.BikeStats.Select(item => new BikeStat()
                {
                    Id = item.Id,
                    StatDate = item.StatDate
                }).ToList() as ICollection<BikeStat>)
            }).ToList();
```

This works, but is a bit pants. So I changed the serialisation to this:

```
            var d = db.Bikes.Include("BikeStats").ToList();
            string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d, 
                Formatting.Indented, 
                new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore, PreserveReferencesHandling=PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects });

            return s;
```

Which works, but it doesn't. It adds "\r\n" as a string to the response, turns all quote marks into \", puts '$' in front of some values and Chrome still thinks it's XML.

I changed the class to have this and it all magically works. Why? and is there a better way so that I can still access Bike from BikeStat?

```
[JsonIgnore]
    public Bike Bike { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing your code to look like this

```
public class BikeStation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CentreName { get; set; }
    public string StationName { get; set; }
}

public class Bike
{
    public string ShortBikeName { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<BikeStat> BikeStats { get; set; }
}

public class BikeStat
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StatDate { get; set; }
    public Bike Bike { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You mean remove virtual to enable eager loading? I tried that and it still fails whether I do not call Include (i.e. get no navigation data) or call Include.

Comment: I kind of got it working by following this (http://blog.learningtree.com/working-with-the-entity-framework-and-the-web-api/), basically reformat the navigation data as a new class, which is painful. The other suggestion is to use JSON.Net to replace the data contract serialiser, but I have no idea how. 

Really, for this to not work out of the box is pretty pants.